# How do I transfer Ubuntu 16.04 from external USB drive to an inetrnal disk partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb

I am currently working on Ubuntu 16.04 booting from an external, single partition, USB drive, but I would like to transfer everything to a dedicated Linux partition on the internal drive.
The internal disk drive is currently configured as a single partition with Windows 10.
May you suggest a smooth way to do that?

Thank you in advance

gman

Comment: You can do that, but you need to apply some little patches. It's not that hard. Check out this link https://github.com/lemonsqueeze/boot-chroot

Comment: I am using that patch successfully, but you must be careful, because it may be incompatible after upgrades.

Comment: Thanks kenn, looks interesting but, as you say, a little bit dangerous because the involved machine is under automatic upgrades

Comment: Does your USB have a Persistent install of Ubuntu or a Full install of Ubuntu? If you want to copy a Full install, shrink the Windows partition using Windows Disk Management, Use the Ubuntu Live USB to install Ubuntu to the empty space using "Something else", Put the bootloader on sda, Once install is complete copy home directory using rsync or grsync as shown elsewhere in Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: An alternate method that works with both a Full or Persistent install to USB, is to shrink the Windows partition using Disk Management, (it is way faster than GParted and safer for a Windows install), and copy/paste the Ubuntu partition using GParted, (or Disks), (while booted from a third drive). Grub will then need to be installed on the HDD.

Comment: My USB has a Full Ubuntu installation. Your last suggestion is going to be my first try, thanks @C.S.Cameron and thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. You've to install ubuntu in internal hdd and install all the apps.

You can resize the windows 10 partition to create a new partition and install ubuntu on the new partition. You can resize windows 10 partition using `gparted` when booting from usb.

Comment: It is safer to resize the Windows partition using Windows Disk Management.